# Convert varchar to date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column of Varchar Datatype with date in the format: `11 december 2013`, and I like to convert all data in this column to date format like:      `2013-12-11`. How would I do it in MySQL?

Comment: Since you haven't made an effort to solve the problem yourself, it seems that [you are looking to hire a paid freelancer to do it for you](http://www.freelancer.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `str_to_date()` function while converting a varchar date to real date

```
mysql> select str_to_date('11 december 2013','%d %M %Y');
+--------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('11 december 2013','%d %M %Y') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 2013-12-11                                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple query with [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%Y-%m-%d') `FormattedDate`
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Link is dead. Here are others:
https://sql.sh/fonctions/date_format

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format